# PHP command in Bash does not execute code

Tags: php, bash, terminal

Ok, so I have a problem with this thing I found on a MacBook Air. It's called terminal and you can do crazy stuff on it. So anyways, when I enter the command "php" it gives me a multiline console but it doesn' do anything when I run a line of php! For instance, I type echo "Hello World" but it just returns it like a typewriter and nothing happens! Can someone please tell me what is going on, and is there a way to exit this?

Comment: If you call it with `php -a` you can type code which will be executed directly. With `php path_to_file.php` you can run a php file. You can find a full list of commands here: http://php.net/manual/de/features.commandline.options.php

Comment: Hit Ctrl+D and it'll execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly check if you have php properly installed:

type in console:

```
php -v
```

you should see version of installed php for ex.:

> PHP 7.3.3 ...

to run single line of code from console you do it this way:

```
php -r 'echo "\nHello World\n";'
```

where **\n** is new line character.

to enter interactive mode and run multiple lines of code:

```
php -a
```

and once you see:

> Interactive mode enabled
>
> php >

type:

```
echo "\nHello World\n";
```

and hit [Enter] key.

that's it.

to leave interactive mode type:

```
exit
```

note lack of **;** at the end.

If you want to run from console a php code that you have in a file:

```
php -f <path-to-the-file>
```

but this is a default behavior of php so if you miss flag -f and just type:

```
php
```

it will do nothing, expecting you providing it a path to file after the php  like in the example with flag **-f**:

```
php <path-to-file>
```

So if a programmer intention is to enter an interactive mode but he types only `php` without any flags, the php **will not** warn about missing path to the file so programmer may have the impression he's into php interactive mode as he wanted but this is not true.

to see all possible options in php cli, type:

```
php --help
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped so much.

Comment: @MrPizzaGuy no problem, see update of my answer for possible reason of your problems with php in cli mode

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you just type php into the terminal it will start a php server process on the local mac.  If you want to run a script you have to cd in to to the working directory and type `php filename.php`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use PHP code directly you must enter `php -a` without `a` flag you will just enter in php environment.

Answer (score 0):

When running the `php` command directly from your command line, it behaves as it is reading a `.php` from the command line

You noticed that it just echo's back any thing you write toward it, this is the same as it is executing a `.php` file, its echoíng any html back to the browser

Example:

```
$ php
sss
<?PHP
echo 'Hello!';
?>
More data!
```

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> (to signal that the end of the filehas reached)

Output:

```
sss
Hello!More data!
```